# Golang project structure domain model package

Tags: go

I have a question about the Golang project structure. 
Assume that this is my project structure in high level:

[image]

The project `fzr` defines yaml structure, which I need to parse and provide functions, to get data on top of this yaml file content.

- the `model` contains all the structs
- the `provider` contains the `yaml.Unmarshal` to parse the structs and provide objects which contain all the yaml file data

Assume that I need to provide **functions on top of the structs data**, such as:

- `getUserApps`
- `getServices`
- `getUserServices`
- `getApps`
- `getUserByIde`
- etc..

Where should these functions be placed? Maybe in a new created package under `fzr`? I don't want to use the flat option.

Of course, I can place some files under the provider package, which contains all the function there, but not sure if this would be clean? Go package structure is quite confusing me.

Comment: Create a package for fzr inside model in which there can be two files one contains the list of structs and other one contains the unmarshal functions. Or you can create a package named store to unmarshal yaml and store the data inside db.

Comment: @Himanshu - but the root is called `fzr` :) how do you called to package inside `fzr` with all access functions ?

Comment: there is one more option then you can add all the files structs in a single file called global.go and then unmarshal inside fzr.go

Comment: @Himanshu - im a bit confused, can you provide a answer that descirbe it ? for example assume that I've only `fzr` package and inside it having `modles` package , where do you put the `yaml.Unmarshal` and the `accessFunctions` ?

Comment: it will be great if you can provide example in my context

Comment: you said you do want a flat structure because in your case you can add a file in models containing the structs and fzr.go will contains all functions unmarshaling the yaml.

Comment: @Himanshu - I dont want flat structure, assume that I've only fzr package and inside it having modles package , where do you put the yaml.Unmarshal and the accessFunctions ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180609/discussion-between-himanshu-and-shopia-t).

Comment: @shopiaT There are no "inside" packages and no "subpackages" in Go. All packages are equal and it does not matter the tiniest bit where you place them on the FS. Take a look at how other OS programs are structured on disk.